# How do I sell shares in a company when I have Stock Certificates and can't locate the company?

Tags: stocks, share-certificate

I have about 12,000 shares of stock in a company called Cardinal and Parker Inc.  I want to sell my shares of said company but the problem I'm having is I can't seem to locate any current information on the company.  The only thing I can find out about them is they were incorporated on July 10,1987 and the company hasn't paid state taxes since 1988 but the company has not closed.  Ive tried researching to see if there was a merger or acquisition but I can't find anything concrete.  Does anybody have any advice on what you do?

Comment: What country is it incorporated in?

Comment: A websearch leads to [this page](https://www.parkcompanies.org/cardinal-and-parker-inc) which indicates they are registered in Delaware, under the auspices of [Delaware Business Incorporators, Inc.](https://www.delawarebusinessincorporators.com/), whose business seems to be forming Delaware companies. It's _possible_ that if you contact them you can get more information, although the "_according to the relevant government agency, it is now of unknown status_" from the first link doesn't inspire confidence that there's anything to salvage.

Comment: OP could probably go to the Delaware Secretary of State web site and look up the company’s registration number to get any more historical data.